# How to call data from ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android-fragments, arraylist

I'm making a dictionary, the search is successful, but when I want to display the details of the word it doesn't work. I don't know where the error lies. Maybe the coding is wrong or missing.

I've tried using a command like the one below, only it displays the same data, you can see an example in the image below

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(mSource.get(position));
            }
        });
```

When I search for the word in the search it appears like the image below

[image]

but when I want to see the details of that word, it displays the details of another word. same result also for all list views

[image]

I have also tried the command as below, it doesn't display detailed data at all. maybe I coded wrong

```
dicList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (adapter != null)                     
                    adapter.getItem(position);           
           }
       });
```

here is some of the code. please tell me if you need another code.
Thank You

KamusActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class kamusActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    MenuItem menuSetting;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    DictionaryFragment dictionaryFragment;
    BookmarkFragment bookmarkFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kamus);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);

        dictionaryFragment = new DictionaryFragment();
        bookmarkFragment = BookmarkFragment.getNewInstance(dbHelper);
        goToFragment(dictionaryFragment, true);

        dictionaryFragment.setOnFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String value) {
                String id = Bahasa.getState(kamusActivity.this,"dic_type");
                int dicType = id == null? R.id.action_it:Integer.valueOf(id);
                goToFragment( DetailFragment.getNewInstance(value,dbHelper,dicType),false);
            }
        });
        bookmarkFragment.setOnFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String value) {
                String id = Bahasa.getState(kamusActivity.this,"dic_type");
                int dicType = id == null? R.id.action_it:Integer.valueOf(id);
                goToFragment( DetailFragment.getNewInstance(value,dbHelper,dicType),false);
            }
        });

        EditText edit_search = findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
        edit_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){
                dictionaryFragment.filterValue(charSequence.toString());
            }
            
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){

            }
        });

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        menuSetting = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);

        String id = Bahasa.getState(this,"dic_type");
        if (id != null)
            onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(Integer.valueOf(id)));
        else {
            ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(R.id.action_it);
            dictionaryFragment.resetDataSource(source);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_it) {
            Bahasa.saveState(this,"dic_type", String.valueOf(id));
            ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(id);
            dictionaryFragment.resetDataSource(source);
            menuSetting.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_bibt_2));
            return true;
        }else if (id == R.id.action_ti){
            Bahasa.saveState(this,"dic_type", String.valueOf(id));
            ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(id);
            dictionaryFragment.resetDataSource(source);
            menuSetting.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_btbi_2));
            return true;
        }
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_bookmark){
            String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
            if(!activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())){
                goToFragment(bookmarkFragment, false);
            }
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    void goToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean isTop){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        if (!isTop)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())){
            menuSetting.setVisible(false);
            toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbar.setTitle("Bookmark");
        }else {
            menuSetting.setVisible(true);
            toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar.setTitle("");
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

detailfragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private String value = "";
    private TextView tvWord;
    private ImageButton btnBookmark;
    private WebView tvWordTranslate;
    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private int mDicType;



    public DetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static DetailFragment getNewInstance(String value, DBHelper dbHelper, int dicType){
        DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
        fragment.value = value;
        fragment.mDBHelper = dbHelper;
        fragment.mDicType = dicType;
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detia, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        tvWord = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWord);
        tvWordTranslate = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWordTranslate);
        btnBookmark = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnBookmark);

        final Word word = mDBHelper.getWord(value, mDicType);
        tvWord.setText(word.key);
        tvWordTranslate.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, word.value,"text/html", "utf-8",null);

        Word bookmarkWord = mDBHelper.getWordFromBookmark(value);
        int isMark = bookmarkWord == null ? 0 : 1;
        btnBookmark.setTag(isMark);

        int icon = bookmarkWord == null ? R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border : R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill;
        btnBookmark.setImageResource(icon);

        btnBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                int i = (int) btnBookmark.getTag();
                if (i == 0) {
                    btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill);
                    btnBookmark.setTag(1);
                    mDBHelper.addBookmark(word);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border);
                    btnBookmark.setTag(0);
                    mDBHelper.removeBookmark(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

dictionaryfragment.java

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DictionaryFragment extends Fragment {

    private String value = "Hello everyone!!!";
    private FragmentListener listener;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView dicList;
    private ArrayList<String> mSource = new ArrayList<String>();

    public DictionaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dictionary, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        dicList = view.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dicList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (adapter != null)
                    adapter.getItem(position); /// here i'm stuck
           }
       });
    }

    public void resetDataSource(ArrayList<String> source){
        mSource = source;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void filterValue(String value){
        adapter.getFilter().filter(value);
        int size = adapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0 ; i<size;i++){
            if (adapter.getItem(i).startsWith(value)){
                dicList.setSelection(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void setOnFragmentListener(FragmentListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context mContext;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_dic.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private String DATABASE_LOCATION = "";
    private String DATABASE_FULL_PATH = "";

    private final String TBL_BI_BT = "bi_bt";
    private final String TBL_BT_BI = "bt_bi";
    private final String TBL_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";

    private final String COL_KEY = "key";
    private final String COL_VALUE = "value";

    public SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;

        DATABASE_LOCATION = "data/data/" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/database";
        DATABASE_FULL_PATH = DATABASE_LOCATION + DATABASE_NAME;

        if (!isExistingDB()){
            try {
                File dbLocation = new File(DATABASE_LOCATION);
                dbLocation.mkdirs();

                extractAssetToDatabaseDirectory(DATABASE_NAME);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FULL_PATH, null);

    }

    boolean isExistingDB() {
        File file = new File(DATABASE_FULL_PATH);
        return file.exists();
    }

    public void extractAssetToDatabaseDirectory(String fileName)
        throws IOException { // copy the database

        int length;
        InputStream sourceDatabase = this.mContext.getAssets().open(fileName);
        File destinationPath = new File(DATABASE_FULL_PATH);
        OutputStream destination = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((length = sourceDatabase.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            destination.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        sourceDatabase.close();
        destination.flush();
        destination.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public ArrayList<String> getWord(int dicType){
        String tableName = getTableName(dicType);
        String q = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q, null);

        ArrayList<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.moveToNext()){
            source.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_KEY)));
        }
        return source;
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public Word getWord(String key, int dicType){
        String tableName = getTableName(dicType);
        String q = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" WHERE upper([key]) = upper(?)";
        Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q,new String[]{key});

        Word word = new Word();
        while (result.moveToNext()){
            word.key = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_KEY));
            word.value = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_VALUE));
        }
        return word;
    }

    public void addBookmark(Word word){
        try {
            String q = "INSERT INTO bookmark(["+COL_KEY+"],["+COL_VALUE+"]) VALUES (?, ?);";
            mDB.execSQL(q, new Object[]{word.key, word.value});
        }catch (SQLException ex){

        }
    }

    public void removeBookmark(Word word){
        try {
            String q = "DELETE FROM bookmark WHERE upper(["+COL_KEY+"]) = upper(?) AND ["+COL_VALUE+"] = ?;";
            mDB.execSQL(q, new Object[]{word.key, word.value});
        }catch (SQLException ex){

        }
    }

    public void removeBookmark(String key){
        try {
            String q = "DELETE FROM bookmark WHERE upper(["+COL_KEY+"]) = upper(?);";
            mDB.execSQL(q, new Object[]{key});
        }catch (SQLException ex){
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public ArrayList<String> getAllWordFromBookmark() {
        String q = "SELECT * FROM bookmark ORDER BY [date] DESC;";
        Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q,null);

        ArrayList<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.moveToNext()){
            source.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_KEY)));
        }
        return source;
    }

    public boolean isWordMark(Word word) {
        String q = "SELECT * FROM bookmark WHERE upper([key]) = upper(?) AND [value] = ?";
        Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q, new String[]{word.key, word.value});
        return result.getCount() > 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public Word getWordFromBookmark(String key) {
        String q = "SELECT * FROM bookmark WHERE upper([key]) = upper(?)";
        Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(q, new String[]{key});
        Word word = null;
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            word = new Word();
            word.key = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_KEY));
            word.value = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_VALUE));
        }
        return word;
    }

    public String getTableName(int dicType){
        String tableName = "";
        if (dicType == R.id.action_ti){
            tableName = TBL_BT_BI;
        }else if (dicType == R.id.action_it){
            tableName = TBL_BI_BT;
        }
        return tableName;
    }

    public void clearBookmark() {
        try {
            String q = "DELETE FROM bookmark;";
            mDB.execSQL(q);
        }catch (SQLException ex){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not everyone will analyze this much text. Please ask questions with clarity and specify where you need help."